# DAX COUNTIF equivalent, based on aggregated results

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have been racking my brain on this, I have a report that I need to get a count of different thresholds from the result of a measure. My data is daily, but the report needs to be at the weekly level. When I have tried to do a = CALCULATE ( COUNT( AgentData[AgentName] ), FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT( AgentData, AgentData[Start of Week], AgentData[AgentName] ), [AHT] < 600 )

This seems to count all days in the week where [AHT] < 600, however I am looking for a count of all agents in the week where [AHT] < 600. AHT is calculated using the fields AgentData[HandleTime] / AgentData[Chats]

The result I'm looking for, as an aggregate of weekly data. Can this be done? Ideally, the time interval would be based on what is selected in the pivot, and would work if at the daily, weekly, monthly level.

| Week | Total Agents | < 600 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Week 1 | 100 | 25 |
| Week 2 | 125 | 40 |

Sample data:

| Date | Agent Name | HandleTime | Chats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2022 | Bob | 6000 | 10 |
| 5/2/2022 | Bob | 4800 | 11 |
| 5/1/2022 | Lucia | 5200 | 8 |

Total Agents is a distinctcount of AgentData[AgentName]

Comment: Could you provide sample data? Is the *Total Agents* a measure?

Comment: Total Agents is a distinctcount of AgentData[AgentName].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `AgentData[AgentName]` from `ALLEXCEPT`, replace `COUNT` with `TotalAgents` measure (if that one should be used for) and it should work properly:

```
a = 
CALCULATE ( 
   [TotalAgents], 
   FILTER ( 
      ALLEXCEPT( AgentData, AgentData[Start of Week] ), 
      [AHT] < 600 
   )
)
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to be calculating based on the total agents, the count for a week is 100, <600 is 93, and 600-650 is 82. It's hard to say but it looks like it's checking if any day in the week is <600 instead of calculating the AHT for the period and counting from that.

Comment: Well, I've pulld sample data into the model and created exact measure and it works. Maybe there are some issues with your model or data? Week names are coming from calendar table or agent table itself?

Comment: The week names are coming from the agent table itself. I'll look into it more but at least I think this is a good starting point. I'm probably just missing something obvious at this point. Thank you!